# Error in if (dataclass == "data.frame") { : the condition has length > 1

Tags: r

I defined a function in R 4.2.0.

```
Beta_NTI<-function(phylo,comun,beta.reps=999){
  require(picante)
  match.phylo.comun = match.phylo.data(phylo, t(comun))
  beta.mntd.weighted = as.matrix(comdistnt(t(match.phylo.comun$data),cophenetic(match.phylo.comun$phy),abundance.weighted=T))
  
  rand.weighted.bMNTD.comp = array(c(-999),dim=c(ncol(match.phylo.comun$data),ncol(match.phylo.comun$data),beta.reps))
  for (rep in 1:beta.reps) {
    rand.weighted.bMNTD.comp[,,rep] = as.matrix(comdistnt(t(match.phylo.comun$data),taxaShuffle(cophenetic(match.phylo.comun$phy)),abundance.weighted=T,exclude.conspecifics = F))
    print(c(date(),rep))
  }
  weighted.bNTI = matrix(c(NA),nrow=ncol(match.phylo.comun$data),ncol=ncol(match.phylo.comun$data))
  for(columns in 1:(ncol(match.phylo.comun$data)-1)) {
    for(rows in (columns+1):ncol(match.phylo.comun$data)) {
      rand.vals = rand.weighted.bMNTD.comp[rows,columns,];
      weighted.bNTI[rows,columns] = (beta.mntd.weighted[rows,columns] - mean(rand.vals)) / sd(rand.vals)
      rm("rand.vals")
    }
  }
  rownames(weighted.bNTI) = colnames(match.phylo.comun$data);
  colnames(weighted.bNTI) = colnames(match.phylo.comun$data);
  return(as.dist(weighted.bNTI))
}
```

When I run it as

```
Beta_NTI(bac_tree,t(bac))
```

, I got "Error in if (dataclass == "data.frame") { : the condition has length > 1".
But it was no problem in R 4.1.0.

bac_tree, a phylogenetic tree; bac, an otu table with sample ID as colname and otu number as rowname

Comment: What result do you get when you type `class(bac_tree)` into the console? Have you run `debug(Beta_NTI)` to see which line throws the error?

Comment: R 4.1.0 changed warnings to errors when `if()` is used on vectors of length > 1.  One of your functions must essentially be doing `dataclass <- class(data)` and then have `if(dataclass == "data.frame")`. This is bad practice because an object can have more than one `class`. This is why we have `is.class` functions to test if an object is a class. It should be using `if(is.data.frame(data))` instead. The simplest solution for you is probably to continue using an older version of R until the package authors make the fix.

Comment: Otherwise you could run `traceback()` to locate the problem and try to fix it yourself.

Comment: @GregorThomas warnings when if() is used on vectors of length > 1 were changed to errors in R 4.2.0, not 4.1.0. Which makes sense for this problem :)

Comment: @GregorThomas This problem was solved when I added `if(is.data.frame(data))` in this function. Thank you very much.